# Extract two numbers out of a string in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a string that I need two numbers extracted and separated into two columns like this.

```
ID:1234567 RXN:89012345
ID:12345 RXN:678901

Column 1   Column 2
1234567    89012345
12345      678901
```

The numbers can be varying number of characters. I was able to get column 2 number by using the following function:

=RIGHT(G3,FIND("RXN:",G3)-5)

However, I'm having a hard time getting the ID number separated.

Also, I need this to be a function as I will be using a macro to use over many spreadsheets.

Comment: do those strings always start with `ID:`? how about `MID(G3,3,FIND(" ", g3))`

Comment: Is `ID:1234567 RXN:89012345` in the same cell? You could also do a Data --> Text to Columns, using a space delimiter to separate the two.  To get rid of the "ID" and "RXN", see @ML's answer.

Comment: Marc - The data does always start with ID:, however your function produces the result ":1234567 RX" and ":12345 RX".

Comment: If you're doing a macro anyway why not use the VBA method of `split`? You could split by `:` and doing so would give you an array that you would then pull your number out of.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is:

1. **Select** all your data - assuming it is in a string all the time - which means one cell has one row with ID&RXN nos. So if you have 100 rows such data, select all of it
2. Go to the Data tab, Text to columns
3. Choose `Delimited`>>`Next`>> choose `Space` here, in `Other`, type a colon(`:`) >> `Finish`
4. You will get "ID" in first column, every cell; ID no in second column every cell; RXN in third column every cell and RXN no in 4th column every cell.
5. **Delete** unwanted columns

Comment: Sorry, but I should have mentioned that I do need a formula as I will be using a macro to apply to many spreadsheets at once.

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("ID:",A1)+LEN("ID:"),FIND(" ",A1,FIND("ID:",A1)+LEN("ID:"))-FIND("ID:",A1)-LEN("ID:"))
```

and copy down.  In **C1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("RXN:",A1)+LEN("RXN:"),9999)
```

and copy down:

[image]

*The column **B** formulas are a pretty standard way to capture a sub-string encapsulated by two other sub-strings.*

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always as you show it,then:

```
B1:  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),":",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))

C1:  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),":",REPT(" ",99)),3*99,99))
```

We substitute a long string of spaces for the `space` and `:` in the original string.  Then we extract the 2nd and 4th items and trim off the extra spaces.